# Android Fragment back stack causing wired issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having fragment in a single activity in the following sequence.

fragment 1 --> fragment 2 --> fragment 3 --> fragment 4

I am using below code for fragment transaction.

```
mFragmentTransaction=mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFragment,fragmentname);
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
mFragmentTransaction.commit();
```

What i want to do is when user is on fragment 3 or 4 then on back press 
if user is on fragment 4 then  fragment 4 --> fragment 3 --> fragment 1.
if user is on fragment 3 then fragment 3 --> fragment 1.

I am using following code in onback press.

```
if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment 3")!=null){


            mFragmentManager.popBackStack("fragment 2",FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);



        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

But it cause wired issue on on back press as follow.

fragment 4 --> fragment 1 instead of fragment 4 --> fragment 3 --> fragment 1.
fragment 3 --> fragment 1

please help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have another nested if statement. You have the one to check if the fragment is null or not, but then you need to check if that fragment is visible.

```
if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment 3")!=null){
     if(mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("fragment 3").isVisible()){
        mFragmentManager.popBackStack("fragment 2",FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
else{
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```